# Do saved presets override manual changes in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

If you make manual adjustments in Lightroom and then add a preset, do those manual changes go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only the settings specified in the preset are changed to the preset's values. The rest (if any) are not changed.